# How to move wpf application into minimize tray at Window Start-up C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, startup, setup-project

I have created setup of my application using Windows Installer.

Now I want to Start application at Windows Start-Up and move it system minimize tray as i don't want to display GUI(View) at Windows Start-Up.

I have searched in Google and i found to use Registry key But that is not enough for me as i also want to move to system minimize tray and application run.

My purpose to do it is, user do not feels annoying when application starts every time when he/she starts system.

Can anyone have answer?
Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

In your application, add an event handler for the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event. In that handler, add the following code:

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

This will minimise the application when it starts.

To start the application when the computer starts, you'll need to add your program into Windows Scheduler and set it to run at startup. You can find out more on the [Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/schedule-a-task) page at MSDN.

Comment: I want minimize when it starts when computer starts not every time when use click on icon

Answer (score 4):

You also have to set this property to remove it from the taskbar

```
ShowInTaskbar= false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer is late, but I still want to write it down to help those who haven't found solutions yet.

Firstly you need to add a function to minimize your app to tray when it autostarts as system startup.

1. In your App.xaml file, change the original `StartupUri=...` to `Startup="App_Startup"` as below. **App_Startup** is your function name and can be changed.

```
<Application x:Class="Yours.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="App_Startup">
```

2. In your App.xaml.cs file. Add the function below:

```
public partial class App : Application
{    
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Process command line args
        var isAutoStart = false;
        for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (e.Args[i] == "/AutoStart")
            {
                isAutoStart = true;
            }
        }

        // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        if (isAutoStart)
        {
            mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        mainWindow.OnAutoStart();
    }
}
```

3. In your MainWindow.xaml.cs, add a function as below:

```
public void OnAutoStart()
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        //Must have this line to prevent the window start locatioon not being in center.
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        Hide();
        //Show your tray icon code below
    }
    else
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

Then you should set you app utostart as system start.

4. Now if you have a switch to decide whether you app to autostart as system start, you can just add the function below as your switch status changed event function.

```
private void SwitchAutoStart_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
    var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
    if (key == null) return;
    if (SwitchAutoStart.IsOn)
    {
        key.SetValue("Your app name", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + " /AutoStart");
    }
    else
    {
        key.DeleteValue("Your app name", false);
    }
}
```

If you want to automatically start the application for **all users** on Windows startup, just replace the forth line with

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
```

^_^